# make custom display for date in button

Tags: android, date

I have a button, so when clicked it open datepicker and show it in text button after user select a date...How I custom date display to look a like this

[image: custom style]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation for "day_name month" and for "day", and another LinearLayout inside with vertical orientation for "day_name" and "month".

Something like :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=1
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=1 />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=2 />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=1 />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the basic structure. Now you need to use tags like textAllignment and textStyle (bold) on the textView, and add the ids so you can change programmatically its values after selecting a date.

Comment: how I put it inside a button?

Comment: Why not make the hole LinearLayout cickeable ?